# Submit_Click Successful registration? asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, response.redirect

I have a button that submit the info to register an account in my database.

```
<asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="Submit_Click" Text="Submit" class="login"/><br />
```

In my aspx.cs for this page what should I put to display a message that says you have successfully registered?

I tried a redirect as an alternative `Response.Redirect(success.html);` but I get an error.

Comment: Try Response.Redirect("success.html", true); which will kill the thread

Comment: That gets rid of the error, but it doesn't redirect. Thanks for that help tho!

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 Response.Redirect("success.html",true);
```

or gave him a alert by saying registration succesfull

```
 alert("registration succesfull");
```

in code behind it will

```
 ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "sas", "<script> alert('Inserted successfully');</script>", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will display a pop up window as `Successfully Registered` and also Page will be `refreshed` or  `redirected` based on your Page name.

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Succesfully Registered');window.location.replace('Nameofyouraspxpage.aspx');</script>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No `Response.Redirect` is not a good way for this little problem.

you should add a `asp:label` on your page and set its text to null ("")

```
<asp:Label ID="lblMessage" Text="" runat="server" />
```

at code behind, you add the following line at the end of your function

```
this.lblMessage.Text = "Successfully Registered!";
```

Comment: Place your label where you want to show your message.
And then do what I have suggested you. It will surely solve your problem. Goodluck